# PHP/Apache showing site from different server

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I have two AMP servers in my local network. Server 1 is 'online' and server 2 is just for local testing. Server 1 has a small sized harddisk and runs 24/7. Server 2 is on my workstation and has a large harddisk. Sometimes, I would like to show my users a page (containing lots of large images for example) from Server 2 using Server 1 as a redirector. How to do this?

Using Server 2 as the 'online' server is not an option (not 24/7). And giving Server 1 more harddisk space also is not an option for me.

Comment: curl the page from server 2 if it fails (ie: server 2 is turned off) throw friendly error for user

Comment: I'm assuming this is an intranet. If so, why not directly access Server2? If Server1 is not online, then there's no way for it to redirect requests without possibly a router setup.

Comment: You could use a reserve proxy like nginx

Comment: Why don't you set it up as a second 'online' server with a subdomain or something like dev.domain.com? If you only want access to it a certain times just turn off public access to it when you don't want others to get to it.

Comment: or you could use 3 lines of php on server 1 and do a curl request oO stop over complicating things.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that was the easy answer I was looking for!